# React axios Cors Policy error with 3rd side server

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios, openid-connect

I have react client that sends get request to my node server using axios, which received in my server after I allowed cors,
and the server passes the request to 3rd side server which I have no access to its configuration at all so I cannot allow cors in that server ,and the request sent with the client Origin of course. For that reason, I get No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. I read and try many ways to solve that, still without success. Any idea how to solve that?
FYI if I send the request from my server without the client its success.
Edit:
React:

```
axios.get(host+url).then(...)
```

Node:

```
app=express();
....some code here for init auth params(clientId,secret)
and session init
app.get(url,auth.authenticate(failUrl,successUrl);
app.use(auth.init());
```

The auth.authenticate is libary that after logic that I am not fully aware  of taking some params of openid connect authentication, and send get request with all of this params.
At the end of the operation I should be redirected to fail/success url, however I am not even get there.

Comment: why don't you take out url, and parameters from the client request and make your own request to 3rd server.

Comment: It is authentication request that have logic in my server that cannot be on the client side, include built in libaries and dependencies

Comment: Can you post some examples of your Axios request, and the handler in Node please. It's impossible to assist further with the provided detail

Comment: I added some code to look at

Comment: can you try something like - app.get(url, youCustomFunc, auth.authenticate(fail, succ));

putting your middleware in between and modifying the request headers.